# Code to add something to startup doesn't make the key

Tags: c++, registry

I'm experimenting with adding something to the startup. My code doesn't add anything but doesn't give any errors too.

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
DWORD pathLen = 0;

_tcscpy_s(szPath, _T("c:/app.exe"));
pathLen = _tcslen(szPath);

HKEY newValue;
if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),&newValue) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return -1;
}
DWORD pathLenInBytes = pathLen * sizeof(*szPath);
if (RegSetValueEx(newValue,TEXT("AppV1"),0, REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) szPath,pathLenInBytes) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    RegCloseKey(newValue);
    return -1;
}
RegCloseKey(newValue);
return TRUE;
```

I'm not seeing a newkey in the regedit on my windows 7.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Well, you don't have any error handling. Instead of asking us, why not ask the OS? It knows better what happened than we do.

Comment: Have you debug your code?? you may found that , one above function may not return ERROR_SUCCESS.

Comment: I've just tested the if tests, he doesn't come in the if tests. So it must succeed?

Comment: Found it, you need admin rights.

Comment: @user1480139: No you don't. Not for `HKCU`.

Comment: @MSalters then I don't see the error :s I putted debug code and the code doesn't fail but doesn't add something too.

Comment: This code works as intended as user here. Maybe some right restrictions or antivirus protection ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, turned off my antivirus and everything workes like a charm.